# Using tilde in ansible "when" statements to build file names from variables

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

The behavior of ~ in ansible "when" statements is puzzling.  For example, if LIB is a fact, set by set_fact, with a value of "lib64" I would expect the following statement to be true if /usr/lib64/cernlib/2006 exists, and false otherwise:

```
  when: '"/usr/" ~ LIB ~ "/cernlib/2006" is exists'
```

What I find, though, is that the conditional is always true.

The conditional behaves as expected if I omit reference to LIB and just write:

```
  when: '"/usr/lib64/cernlib/2006" is exists'
```

I can easily imagine a typo that would cause "when" to give me a "false" result, but I'm puzzled by the fact that this always gives me "true".

Am I just doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

[Test syntax](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#test-syntax) says:

> The syntax for using a jinja test is as follows:
>
> variable is test_name

```
- set_fact:
    my_path: "/scratch/{{ LIB }}/cernlib/2006"
- debug:
    msg: "{{ mypath }} exists"
  when: my_path is exists
```

**1)** Using string instead of a variable results in error.

```
- debug:
    msg: "/scratch/test-83.yml exists"
  when: /scratch/test-83.yml is exists
```

shows:

> fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The conditional check '/scratch/test-83.yml is exists' failed. The error was: template error while templating string: unexpected '/'.

**2)** Quotation of the string does not help

```
- debug:
    msg: "/scratch/test-83.yml exists"
  when: "/scratch/test-83.yml" is exists
```

shows:

```
ERROR! Syntax Error while loading YAML.
  did not find expected key
...
The offending line appears to be:

    msg: "/scratch/test-83.yml exists"
  when: "/scratch/test-83.yml" is exists
                               ^ here
This one looks easy to fix.  It seems that there is a value started
with a quote, and the YAML parser is expecting to see the line ended
with the same kind of quote.  For instance:
  when: "ok" in result.stdout
Could be written as:
  when: '"ok" in result.stdout'
Or equivalently:
   when: "'ok' in result.stdout"
```

**3)** Only this specific combination of single and double quotation works

```
- debug:
    msg: "/scratch/test-83.yml exists"
  when: "'/scratch/test-83.yml' is exists"
```

Tested with

```
> ansible --version
ansible 2.7.9
python version = 2.7.15rc1 (default, Nov 12 2018, 14:31:15) [GCC 7.3.0]
```

Comment: Fair enough.  But I'm curious: is there no way to correctly do the concatenation I was attempting?  Also, why does "when" return "true" when I attempt it, rather than "false"?

Comment: Syntax "variable is test_name" is mandatory. I've updated the answer. Probably "when" returns any non-zero as "true".

Comment: > Probably "when" returns any non-zero as "true".   But if I write the "when" without variables, like:  when: "'/scratch/lib64/cernlib/2006' is exists" the test behaves as expected.  (It's true if the path exists, but false otherwise.)  Maybe this is an unintended holdover from some earlier version of ansible?

Comment: Yes. This specific combination works. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Yes, that matches what I found (it also works if you swap the single and double quotes).  But if I use a tilde anywhere in the test, either as I've done above or even as simple as '/usr'~'', the test always returns "true", regardless of whether the path actually exists.